# What codec to use for converting bigint to Long?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I have a bigint field in my Cassandra that I want to convert to a long value.
However, I am not sure how to specify the same in my DataStax-mapper-entity-class.

Here is the code:

```
@PartitionKey(1)
@Column(name="phone", codec=TypeCodec.)
private Double phoneNumber;
```

Can someone please tell what to use in the Column annotation?

**UPDATE**
If I use

```
@PartitionKey(1)
@Column(name="phone")
private Long phoneNumber;
```

I get an error: `java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`

And if I use

```
@PartitionKey(1)
@Column(name="phone")
private Double phoneNumber;
```

I get an error: `Codec not found for requested operation: [bigint <-> java.lang.Double]`

Long or Double does not matter that much to me.
I just want to be able to read it as a number.

I also tried:

```
@PartitionKey(1)
@Column(name="phone", codec=TypeCodec.PrimitiveDoubleCodec.class)
private Double phoneNumber;
```

But then it gives me an error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec$PrimitiveDoubleCodec.<init>()`

Comment: You want to convert to long value, but you define the field as Double

Comment: Double or Long does not matter. I am looking for how to use a codec here. Even if I change it to Long, I dont know what codec to use. I am hoping there should be an inbuilt-codec for this and I won't have to write my own.

Answer (score 2):

By Default Cassandra bigint type map to java long type,So if you define phone as bigint in cassandra then you have to define phone as long in java. If you want to map bigint to Double you have to write custom codec.

Here is the CQL to Java Type Map :

```
--------------------------------
| CQL3 data type  | Java type   |
--------------------------------|
| bigint          | long        |
| double          | double      |
---------------------------------
```

Source : http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping

Comment: I tried long too, did not help. Please see the updated question details

Comment: When you define Long, I think you define phone as double in cassandra

Comment: phone is always defined as bigint in Cassandra. Never changed

Comment: then you are getting this error for another reason.